# Android call Activity specific function from Widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I've following code in my `AppWidgetProvider` class :

```
@Override
    public void onUpdate(
....
  Intent mainIntent = new Intent(ctxt, MainActivity.class);
        mainIntent.putExtra("testExtra",true);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctxt, 0, mainIntent, 0);
        widget.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.buttonAddwidget, pendingIntent);

...
```

this code will launch just main Activity, but I want to call `test()` function from main activity.
How can I do it?
I'm trying to use `getExtra` but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not add some data to the event using `putExtra`- perhaps a boolean flag or something.

Then in `onCreate()` you can check for the presence of the data in the intent (which you can access using `getIntent()`), and call a function if it's there.

**EDIT**

Using the updated code (with the extra) that you've provided above, you then need to something like the following in your `onResume` function within `MainActivity.class`.

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("textExtra"))
    doSomeFunction();
```

`getIntent()` should give you the calling intent. If this doesn't work it's probably to do with your activity's `launchMode` setting, and you may have to override the `onNewIntent()` method to get the intent.

**EDIT 2**

Try adding the following code to your activity. What it does is handles the times when the activity is not created by the intent, so `getIntent()` would return the intent used to *first* create the activity and not the new one (containing the extras). It sets the intent to the new one, so that in `onResume()` you're able to access that extra.

```
 @Override
 protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
     //called when the activity is relaunched by a new intent
     setIntent(intent);
     super.onNewIntent(intent);
 }
```

Comment: Could you write an example. Cause i'm unable to catch `Extra` from `widget` in my `MainActivity`

Comment: I've added such function, but it's not helped. I can't catch extra

Comment: try adding the method from edit2 that I've just updated the question with.